# How to associate Telegram links in Google Chrome with a portable Telegram Messenger?

Tags: google-chrome, telegram-messenger

So, when you have the installer version of Telegram Messenger installed, when you click on a telegram link in chrome (didn't try other browsers) for example [this link](https://t.me/tchannels), you get a page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oKSk.jpg). Now... is it possible to associate these links with a portable version of telegram, if you have both, installer version and portable on your pc?

Answer (score 6):

You just need to re-associate the tg:// file association with the correct app

For that on windows 10 you go to settings, Apps, Default Apps.

At the bottom you will see **Choose default app by protocol** then scroll down until you see **TG URL:Telegram link**. Change as needed.